# Boolean query on elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using boolean queries in elastic search. My queries is

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/population/_search' -d '{
   "query":{
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "term" : { "user" : "rahul" }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term" : { "message" : "dsi" }
            },
            "must_not" : {

                    "country" : "pakistan"

            },
            "should" : [
                {
                    "term" : { "country" : "india" }
                },
                {
                    "term" : { "state" : "karnataka" }
                }
            ],

            "minimum_should_match" : 1,
            "boost" : 1.0
        }}

    }'
```

where user ,state,country are field in my elastic search.
but getting error.

```
    {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object","index":"population","line":13,"col":17}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"population","node":"bECY7K9ORPSuLrXpL1DpDw","reason":{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object","index":"population","line":13,"col":17}}]},"status":400}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `bool/must_not` clause is not correct, you're missing a `term` query

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/population/_search' -d '{
   "query":{
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "term" : { "user" : "rahul" }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term" : { "message" : "dsi" }
            },
            "must_not" : {
                "term": { "country" : "pakistan" }      <--- change this line
            },
            "should" : [
                {
                    "term" : { "country" : "india" }
                },
                {
                    "term" : { "state" : "karnataka" }
                }
            ],

            "minimum_should_match" : 1,
            "boost" : 1.0
        }}

    }'
```

Comment: plz,explain me what changes i need to do.

Comment: you just have a single line to change. See my updated answer. `"term": { "country" : "pakistan" }` instead of just `"country" : "pakistan" `